Unexplained X11 crash with QXL video in kvm/virt-manager under load
I am experiencing a consistent issue with Linux VMs accessed via virt-manager. These VMs, running various versions of Fedora Linux with the Mate desktop environment, crash when the QXL video driver is used and the system is under heavy load for more than an hour (e.g., during make && make install operations).
Symptoms
All the following symptoms must be present; otherwise, it might be a different issue:

The desktop session abruptly ends, causing all running processes to terminate, and the login screen is displayed again.
The kernel log (dmesg) shows the following errors at the end:

qxl 0000:00:01.0: object_init failed for (266240, 0x00000001)
[drm:qxl_gem_object_create [qxl]] *ERROR* Failed to allocate GEM object (262164, 1, 4096, -12)
[drm:qxl_alloc_ioctl [qxl]] *ERROR* qxl_alloc_ioctl: failed to create gem ret=-12

Workaround
Switching the VM’s video driver from QXL to Virtio prevents the crashes. However, this change introduces new issues:

Automatic screen resolution adjustment to the window size no longer works.
Display performance significantly degrades, especially when scrolling through a full terminal window, where you can visibly see each line being redrawn.

Additional Information
I have read similar bug reports, with some mentioning that the issue might be resolved with kernel 6.10. Unfortunately, this is not the case for me. I have encountered the same problem in an older VM with Fedora 34 and kernel 5.16, as well as in newer VMs with Fedora 38 and 40 running kernel 6.10.
This sounds similar, but the error is different:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7004385
One of the affected vms runs Fedora 40 with kernel 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64, it has spice-vdagent-0.22.1-6 installed. This vm currently has 32 GB of RAM allocated.

I experience the same issues running Fedora 40 and kernel 6.10. In the meantime I switched the VM's video driver to Virtio, but as you said I'm experiencing screen adjustments issues, for example the cursor is misaligned to the VM's screen when in full screen mode, but at least I get no more crashes.
If you have managed to find a solution to the QXL or Virtio problems, please do let me know. I'll do the same if I find any

After some testing, I found some kind of workaround.
Using a guest VM with Wayland and virtio driver QXL, the error still happens but doesn't crash the VM: after freezing for a few seconds, the VM returns to normal

I am experiencing the same issue, except that system load doesn't seem to be a factor, other than the fact that it only happens when I am using the VM. Sometimes it happens after 1 hour, other times after 5 hours. Importantly, the problem only started happening after upgrading from Kubuntu 22.04 LTS (kernel version 5.15) to Kubuntu 24.04 LTS (kernel version 6.8).
After rebooting with kernel version 5.15 on Kubuntu 24.04 LTS, the problem seems to have been completely resolved. If this is strictly a kernel bug, and you have confirmed that it occurs on kernel 5.16, then it seems likely that the bug was introduced in the QXL driver included in the Linux kernel 5.16 release. Since booting kernel version 5.15 with an entirely different userspace and distribution release resolved the problem in my case, it seems very likely.
